# Specifying type of function parameters with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to specify a function parameter type in a Node app. This is what I came up with:

```
import express = require("express");

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => { // <- this fails to compile
        // do work
    });
}
```

and it generates this JS, which is not quite right, apparently:

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    module.exports = function (app) {
      //......
    };
});
```

TS definitions are coming from DefinitelyTyped. "express" is defined as

```
declare module "express" {
```

in a .d.ts file.

Obviously i'm doing it wrong.. Any hints?

EDIT:
To expand on basarat's answer:
In csproj file find TypeScriptModuleKind entry, and set it to COMMONJS.

The ts ended up looking like this:

```
import express = require("express");

module.exports = (app: express.Application) => {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        res.send({ name: "woohooo" });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript generated looks like :

```
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
    module.exports = function (app) {
      //......
    };
});
```

because you are compiling with `--module amd`. For node you should use `--module commonjs` see : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

PS: you need to reference the express type definitions for TypeScript to know about express usage : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express-tests.ts#L77 The definition : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express.d.ts